# How to bypass corporate firewall/proxy for Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been trying to create a new Maven Project in Eclipse (I am using Windows 10), however when the project is created, it shows:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'b'.

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 
or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

When looking at the `POM.xml`, it shows..

[image]

I tried deleting the `.m2` folder and `Right-click project` -> `Maven` -> `Update Project..`

It shows me..

[image]

In one solution from another SO post, it mentions the possibility of being behind a proxy.

However by checking from http://amibehindaproxy.com/ it seems I am not behind a proxy.

[image]

I tried making a Maven - Java application project in NetBeans. It seems to be working without showing any errors. But creating a new Maven project in Eclipse always shows up this error dialog box:

[image]

I also create a `settings.xml` in `.m2` folder with the following content. Will this help me get pass the firewall/proxy restrictions?

```
 <proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <host>203.126.xxx.xxx</host>
        <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

I have been trying for over 6 hours and have been browsing various similar posts in SO, I have resolved other dependency issues but unable to resolve this one.

**Que**: So what can I do to create a Maven project without errors from the start?

Comment: You have connection errors to maven central...so Firewall/Proxy issue....

Comment: Did you try to navigate to the directory containing the pom.xml and run maven on the command line? Also you could try to open the maven repo in a browser or at list ping the host.

Comment: @khmarbaise Actually I am happy to hear that. Because I am connecting from my office environment. My windows settings shows a proxy script set by the admin. So I still believe I am behind a proxy. If it is indeed due to restriction from proxy/firewall. At least I know it is not other issues..

Comment: @DrHopfen I can't run on command line because the moment a maven proj is created in eclipse, there is an error. How do you ping the host? Do you mean..`ping 151.101.196.215` ?

Comment: Yes, but in a firewalled environment maybe the ping is blocked as well. If you create the project in eclipse it creates the folder on the disk as well typically in C:\Users\YourName\workspace\project there a pom.xml is created. But I agree wirh khmarbaise that you have no network access to mavne central (try to verify with a browser): https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Comment: @DrHopfen My browser is able to access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ But I doubt so if I ping it because even doing a ping on `www.google.com` will give me a timeout. So if I can access it from browser but can't ping it, will Eclipse be able to access it?

Comment: As suggested before you should try it with maven on the command line. It will be much more helpful regarding error messages. Technically maven/eclipse will do a http(s) request just as you browser does.

Comment: @DrHopfen How do you run it in command line? I have tried `mvn -X`, it seems to be showing the same error message?

Comment: Can you post the output of 'mvn -X install' executed in the project dir?

Comment: @DrHopfen I just created a Maven project at home. Everything is okay, so I guess it's most likely firewall/proxy problem. Any idea how to overcome to firewall/proxy issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169340/discussion-between-drhopfen-and-user3437460).

Comment: @DrHopfen I have resolved the errors. I have created a comprehensive solution for future users. So far all solutions found online are bits and pieces. I would like to thank you and **reward you** for your time spent here. Saw your reward?  ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the solution. I am behind the corporate firewall/proxy. It has been hard for me to get the right fix because there is no detail online guide  despite numerous post asking the same question.

I am providing an (as detail as possible) guide for all future users who face the same problem.

**Step 1 - Creating settings.xml**

We need to setup a proxy for Maven in the `settings.xml` file. If this file is not auto-generated for you, use any text editor such as a notepad and paste in the following:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <username>your username</username>
            <password>your password</password>
            <host>your host</host>
            <port>your port</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

You may also use `NetBeans` to create a Maven project. It will create a `settings.xml` for you. Then use that `settings.xml` file as your template.

**For example:**

```
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <username>anderson</username>
            <password>password123</password>
            <host>proxy.abc.com.</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </proxy>
```

**What is my username?**

I am using my own username issued to me by the company. It is also the username I use to login to my office computer (Windows username)

**What my password?**

I am using the password I use to login to my office computer (Windows password)

**What is my host?**

If you are using Windows

- Internet Explorer
- Connections tab
- LAN Settings
- Look for "Address" textbox (it should be either in "Automatic configuration" or "Proxy Server"). Either one should show you the host name (written on Address textbox). If your company is using a script file for the proxy setup like my case. Read the content of the proxy script file to determine the host name.

**What is my port?**

[image]

In the above step for getting the host name, you will be able to see the port number as well. If your company is using a script. Copy and paste the host on the browser. It will show up or download into your computer. Whatever file extension the script is having, you should be able to read the script content using any text editor. In the script file, you will be able to see the port number your company is using. By reading the script content, I determine my company is using port 8080.

**Step 2 - Placing settings.xml in the right location**

After editing/creating the `settings.xml` file. You can place the file in `.m2` folder. The default location for me in Windows is:

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\.m2
```

If you can't determine the location, you can run the following command in command prompt:

```
mvn -X
```

Look for the location to save your `settings.xml` file

[image]

**Step 3 - Install/Re-update dependencies / clean/build project**

- Right-click your problematic Maven project `->` Run As `->` Maven Install
- Right-click your problematic Maven project `->` Run As `->` Maven Clean

**Your problem should be resolved by now**

Comment: how to determine what is the username and password to be placed in settings.XML since I am not behind any company and I am using maven in my pc

Comment: then do you still need to connect to the internet via a proxy?

Comment: I don't need to connect to internet via proxy because I am using private network( i am not inside any company network ).Please look into my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589259/could-not-understand-about-maven-pom-file-using-eclipse

Comment: So tell me what is necessary to resolve my problem.

Comment: Yours is not a proxy issue. Anyway I have given you some advice in your post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the settings.xml from (conf/settings.xml) general file
2. To m2/Repository.. path
3. Then do an update on proxy

you will find that on your IE Connection